Do U.S. PFIC reporting and taxation laws apply to assets held and/or traded in a 401(k) or HSA account?
U.S. persons who hold (directly or indirectly, as defined in the IRS instructions) financial assets called "passive foreign investment companies" (PFICs) may be required to file Form 8621 with their tax returns, and may be taxed on these assets (or the disposition thereof) in special ways. A PFIC is defined, roughly speaking, as a foreign corporation for which either at least 50% of the corporation's assets produce "passive income" (or are held for that purpose) or at least 75% of the corporation's gross income is passive income. Presumably, most foreign index funds, for instance, would meet this requirement. Unfortunately, sometimes even individual stocks (e.g., for companies that are at an early stage and have little or no operational income) may fall in this category. The reporting requirement alone is quite onerous: the IRS estimates it would take 48 hours and 56 minutes for someone to keep records pertaining to, learn about, and prepare and file Form 8621.
There are some exceptions to the PFIC reporting and taxation rules. For instance, according to the IRS, "a U.S. person that owns stock of a PFIC through a tax-exempt organization or account described in the list below is not treated as a shareholder of the PFIC." This list includes (according to the IRS instructions):


An organization or an account that is exempt from tax under section 501(a) because it is described in section 501(c), 501(d), or 401(a).
A state college or university described in section 511(a)(2)(B).
A plan described in section 403(b) or 457(b).
An individual retirement plan or annuity as defined in section 7701(a)(37).
A qualified tuition program described in section 529 or 530.
A qualified ABLE program described in section 529A.


The list seems to include, for instance, individual retirement accounts (IRAs). However, so far as I can see, certain (common) types of tax-sheltered accounts — 401(k) retirement accounts and HSAs (health savings accounts) in particular — do not fall into any of the cases given above. Does this mean that PFICs held and traded exclusively in 401(k) accounts and HSAs are subject to the Form 8621 reporting and taxation requirements? I have not been able to find anything to the contrary in any official source. I did find one unofficial article stating that "[i]f a PFIC investment is held within a qualified pension plan, such as an Individual Retirement Account (IRA) or a 401(k) plan, the taxpayer is not required to separately report or record it for tax purposes."
References to official IRS publications, U.S. statutes, or case law pertaining to this would be great.

This is a highly technical question and you probably ought to consult a specialist tax lawyer or accountant for advice. Also, the fact that the beneficiary of the account doesn't have to report it, doesn't necessary mean that the non-profit itself doesn't have to report it. Generally, an HSA only invests in cash assets, an HSA invested in an HSA is pretty much unthinkable. Indeed, any closely held asset in an IRA or 401(k) is very remarkable and sophisticated.

"an HSA invested in a PFIC is pretty much unthinkable"

"most foreign index funds, for instance, would meet this requirement." No. Foreign index funds are almost never PFICs. A PFIC is generally a closely held company. It is formed to avoid the taxation of global income of U.S. citizens. The law prevents it from retaining income in order to do so.

Index funds traded on US exchanges are never PFICs. Foreign-traded funds may or may not be PFICs, depending on the nature of their investments, and what reporting, if any, they're making available to the US government and/or shareholders.

@ohwilleke A PFIC is generally a closely held company. It is formed to avoid the taxation of global income of U.S. citizens. - no, not at all. PFIC is a foreign corporation with >75% of its income being passive income. Intentions or closeness of holding has nothing to do with it. See 26 IRC 1297.

@littleadv As a practical matter, however, it works out that way and that is the target of the legislation. An index fund holding foreign assets is generally going to be a U.S. business trust or a U.S. RIC that directly owns foreign assets.

@ohwilleke no, it doesn't work out that way at all. In fact, PFIC is one of the bigger pain points for US expats abroad, and is considered to have been designed to punish American expats.

You quoted:

An organization or an account that is exempt from tax under section 501(a) because it is described in section 501(c), 501(d), or 401(a).

Clearly, 401(k) falls under this definition, being an account exempt from tax under IRC Section 401(a). That one is easy.
The instructions say "See Regulations section 1.1298-1(b)(2) for further information", so let's do that. There we find the official list:

(c) Exceptions—(1) Exception if shareholder is a tax-exempt entity. A shareholder that is an organization exempt under section 501(a) to the extent that it is described in section 501(c), 501(d), or 401(a), a state college or university described in section 511(a)(2)(B), a plan described in section 403(b) or 457(b), an individual retirement plan or annuity as defined in section 7701(a)(37), or a qualified tuition program described in section 529, a qualified ABLE program described in 529A, or a Coverdell education savings account described in section 530 is not required under section 1298(f) and these regulations to file Form 8621 (or successor form) with respect to a PFIC unless the income derived with respect to the PFIC stock would be taxable to the organization under subchapter F of Subtitle A of the Code.

As discussed, a 401(k) plan is a 401(a) plan, so no requirement to report there.
But what about HSA? HSA is governed by the IRC Sec. 223, and IRC Sec. 233(e)(1) says this:

(1) In general
A health savings account is exempt from taxation under this subtitle unless such account has ceased to be a health savings account. Notwithstanding the preceding sentence, any such account is subject to the taxes imposed by section 511 (relating to imposition of tax on unrelated business income of charitable, etc. organizations).

"This Subtitle" refers to the 26 USC Subtitle A, which means that IRC Sec. 1297 that governs PFIC doesn't apply to the HSA accounts (since it is also part of the same subtitle A).
However, to @ohwilleke's comment, there are specific requirements spelled out in IRC Sec. 233(d) that require HSA accounts to be with regulated trustees (basically a US financial institution):

The trustee is a bank (as defined in section 408(n)), an insurance company (as defined in section 816), or another person who demonstrates to the satisfaction of the Secretary that the manner in which such person will administer the trust will be consistent with the requirements of this section.

Those would generally limit investment options since the nature of HSA is such that they have to be liquid and easily accessible. So it is unlikely you'd be able to directly invest in PFICs through HSAs.

Thank you for this nice answer and for the references. I wonder, though -- the part of IRC Sec. 233(e)(1) you quoted seems to suggest that HSA holders are exempt from the taxation requirements of Sec. 1297. But does that also mean that they are exempt from the reporting requirements of that section?

@Duncan44 what reporting requirements?

I was thinking that under ordinary circumstances, Form 8621 would have to be filed even if no extra taxation would result from filing it (and the IRS instructions call it an "Information Return")...

The instructions also mention that "[i]f you are not required to file an income tax return or other return for the tax year, file Form 8621 directly with the Internal Revenue Service Center, Ogden, UT 84201-0201," seeming to suggest that there is a duty to file the form even if no tax is owed.

No, there's no such duty.
